# bash: filter except the latest n records

Tags: bash, elasticsearch

I'm creating a small script that will delete indexes on an Elasticsearch cluster to prevent it for fill up all the storage with logstash data.

I have a list of records, and I would like to keep the latest n records (for example 7) and delete all the others.

I can get the list of the indexes with curl:

```
drakaris:~/ # curl -sL localhost:9200/_cat/indices/logstash-* | awk '{print $3;}' | sort
logstash-2022.12.30
logstash-2022.12.31
logstash-2023.01.01
logstash-2023.01.02
logstash-2023.01.03
logstash-2023.01.04
logstash-2023.01.05
logstash-2023.01.06
logstash-2023.01.07
logstash-2023.01.08
logstash-2023.01.09
```

In my script I would like to keep only the latest 7th indexes and delete all the others (logstash-2022.12.30, logstash-2022.12.31. logstash-2023.01.01, logstash-2023.01.02) using "curl -XDELETE localhost:9200/index".

How can I get these records from an array like that in bash?

Thanks

---

[EDIT]
I solved in this way, just in case someone find it useful

```
RETENTION=7
nbk=$(curl -sL localhost:9200/_cat/indices/logstash-* | awk '{print $3;}' | wc -l)
if [ $nbk -gt $RETENTION ]; then
    echo -e "======== Delete obsolete indexes (retention: $RETENTION)"
    let ntodel=$nbk-$RETENTION
    for efile in $(curl -sL localhost:9200/_cat/indices/logstash-* | awk '{print $3;}' | sort -r | /usr/bin/tail -$ntodel); do
        curl -XDELETE localhost:9200/$efile
        sleep 10
    done
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be pretty simple.  Try this (untested!)

```
drakaris:~/ # curl -sL localhost:9200/_cat/indices/logstash-* | awk '{print $3;}' | sort | tail -n +8
logstash-2022.12.30
logstash-2022.12.31
logstash-2023.01.01
logstash-2023.01.02
```

note that you might want to play with `head` or `tail` here, to get what you need, and then pipe into something like `xargs curl...` to call the `DELETE` endpoint for each one...

Check the manpage for `head` and `tail` and note the use of the `+` in the command.

Answer (score 0):

You could map your list to an array in bash. Use process substitution with `readarray`  (or alias `mapfile`), as a pipe/subshell will not return the variable.

```
readarray -t indexes < <(curl -sL localhost:9200/_cat/indices/logstash-* | awk '{print $3;}' | sort)

# now iterate the array, except the last 7 entries
# (if the array size is < 7, the loop would not enter)
for (( i=0; i < (${#indexes[*]}-7); i++ )); do 
  # delete unwanted indexes
  curl ... ${indexes[$i]}
done
```